# How to show loader image in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to show a loading image when the user hits that particular URL and hide when API is successfully fetched the data.
I am not getting in react to show image initially where I should add code and how to hide when API response in success.

This is the action creator for fetching data.

```
export const fetchEvents = (requestData) => ({
  type: FETCH_EVENTS,
  payload: axios.get(requestData.url, fetchEventsConfig)
})
```

And this is the reducer for fetching data.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case FETCH_EVENTS_FULFILLED:
  const oldState = Object.assign({}, state)
  const response = Object.assign({}, action.payload.data)
  const allResults = oldState.results.concat(response.results)
  return {
    ...state,
    ...response,
    results: allResults
  }
 }
}
```

I am new to this react redux so any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean property in your Redux state to indicate loading state. Let's call it `isLoading`. Set `isLoading` true when you dispatch `FETCH_EVENTS`. Set it false, when you dispatch `FETCH_EVENTS_FULFILLED`.

Pass value of `isLoading` to your React component using `@connect` HOF. Render a loading indicator when value is true, and content when it's false.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_EVENTS: {
        return {...state, isLoading: true}
    }
    case FETCH_EVENTS_FULFILLED: {
        const response = action.payload.data
        const results = [...state.results, ...response.results]

        return {
            ...state,
            ...response,
            results,
            isLoading: false
        }
    }
    case FETCH_EVENTS_FAILURE: {
        return {...state, isLoading: false}
    }
    }
}
```

P.S.

Containing code inside braces after each `switch/case` limits scope of your `const` inside that block.

Answer (score 0):

Write a loader file (loader.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import {ClipLoader} from "react-spinners";

const Loader = ({ loading, message }) => {

    return loading ? (
         <div className='wrapper'>
            <ClipLoader
               size={40}
               color={"#123abc"}
               loading={loading}
             />
             <span className='message'>
                {message}
             </span>
         </div>
    ) : null
};

export default Loader;
```

In Actions:

```
export const GET_SERVICE = '[SERVICE REQUEST] GET LIST';
export const GET_SERVICE_SUCCESS = '[SERVICE REQUEST] GET LIST SUCCESS';
export const GET_SERVICE_FAILURE = '[SERVICE REQUEST] GET LIST FAILURE';

export function getService(options) {
    const request = axios.post('api/services', {options});
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_SERVICE
        });
        try {
            request.then((response) =>
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_SERVICE_SUCCESS,
                    payload: {data: response.data.data, meta: response.data.meta}
                })
            );
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_SERVICE_FAILURE
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    services: [],
    loading: false,
    hasErrors: false,
};

const serviceReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.GET_SERVICE:
            return {...state, loading: true};
        case Actions.GET_SERVICE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                services: [...action.payload.data],
                page: action.payload.meta.page,
                total: action.payload.meta.total
            };
        case Actions.GET_SERVICE_FAILURE:
            return {...state, loading: false, hasErrors: true};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default serviceReducer;
```

Write following code in your component:

```
<div className="flex flex-1 w-full">
   <Loader loading={loading} />
</div>
```