# Contentloader gets stuck while updating data using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Content loader gets stuck while loading data at the component . The content loader at https://github.com/danilowoz/react-content-loader gets stuck while saving data using redux.

I have a react component which on componentdidmount i make calls to several web api and then save the recieved values using redux . During the save the react-content-loader shown gets stuck ?

How do i make the loader without the loader getting stuck ?

Comment: what do you mean its getting stuck ? did you try to disable the loader once you get the data ?

Comment: By stuck i mean the animation part that the content that is getting loaded . Once i get the data i disabling the content loader and showing the actual content .

Comment: not sure but there are simple ways to implement this . checkout my answer

Comment: showing and hiding of loader works fine only problem is during the period the content loader is shown the animation effect of colors moving from left to right is gets stuck

Comment: Please check my answer in another thread: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60872901/7119904)

Answer (score 0):

do a simple `if` on the data for which you want to show this loader.

```
import { Instagram } from 'react-content-loader'

 ...
 ...
render(){

  <div>
   this.state.dataForWhichYouWhereWaiting === null 
   ? 
      <Instagram />
   :
     <ComponentThatDisplaysThatData content={this.state.dataForWhichYouWhereWaiting} />
  </div>

 }
```